# Циклы со списками - C#

Tags: c#, sql, циклы

Подскажите как правильно сделать. 
Есть список, с неопределенным количеством записей:

```
List<string> Sample= new List<string>();
```

Как этот список прогнать через SQL запрос по каждому значению индивидуально, например:

```
SELECT * FROM db WHERE c1 = "значение из LIST"
```

Comment: если c1 это integer то нужно сформировать примерно такое: `SELECT * FROM db WHERE c1 in (1,3,5)`

а список можно сформировать так:
`List<string> Sample = new List<string>() { "1", "3", "5" };
var result = String.Join(", ", names.ToArray());`

Comment: @virex-84, не совсем то что мне нужно, IN подразумевает то что будет загружен весь список в SQL запрос. Мне же необходимо что бы по каждой строке из List, информация выбиралась отдельно.

Comment: тогда нужно в цикле проходить по всем элементам списка, и исполнять запрос для каждого элемента, либо сгенерировать список запросов а позже где-то их исполнять

Comment: @virex-84, собственно вопрос именно в этом. Как правильно оформить цикл)

Comment: хоть for, хоть foreach 

`foreach(String item in Sample)
{

}`

`for(int i = 0; i < Sample.Count; i++) { } `

Comment: Примеры циклов на [T-SQL](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/111401/how-to-iterate-through-a-result-set-by-using-transact-sql-in-sql-serve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте я покажу полный пример.

Во-первых, всегда нужно использовать параметры. Это обезопасит от sql-инъекций и ускорит выполнение запросов.
Во-вторых, всегда нужно освобождать занятые ресурсы, поэтому используем конструкцию `using`.
В-третьих, соблюдаем общепринятый нейминг.

Дано: заполненный список

```
List<string> samples = new List<string>();
```

Код:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();

    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE c1 = @param"; ;
        var sqlParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("param", SqlDbType.NVarChar);

        foreach (var sample in samples)
        {
            sqlParameter.Value = sample;

            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    // здесь получаем значения из ридера
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вы не указали, какую именно СУБД используете. В примере предполагается Sql Server. Если используется другая, замените, соответственно, `SqlConnection` и `SqlDbType` на нужные типы.

Answer (score 1):

Выбирай любой из вариантов:

1.

```
List<string> strings = new List<string> {"a", "b", "asdf"};
//в даном случае это генерация листа, но можно и достать готовый из БД.

strings.ForEach(a=> Console.WriteLine(a)); //вывод в консоль каждого из элементов
```

2.

```
foreach(string item in strings) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

3.

```
for(int i = 0; i < strings.Count; i++) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(strings[i]);
}
```

4. Если же нужен конкретно T-SQL, то я не подскажу, но это легко гуглится по запросу "transact sql foreach"

Comment: Все хорошо, но подправьте один момент: `ForEach` - это не `Linq`, это стандартный метод `List<T>`)